# Is there a way to assign to each element of a tensor a value determined by a generic function in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 3d Tensor, lets call it `values`, and another 2d Tensor called `indexes`. I would like to have another 2d Tensor, lets call it `results`, where the value in `results[i][j]` is equal to `values[indexes[i][j]][i][j]`, so it would be equivalent to writing:

```
for i in range(results.shape[0]):
  for j in range(results.shape[1])):
    results[i][j] = values[indexes[i][j]][i][j]
```

And it is possible to define a function that, for each value of i and j, would return the corresponding value of `results`. Such function would be:

```
def result(i,j):
  return values[indexes[i][j]][i][j]
```

Is there a proper way to assign to `results` the desired values in Tensorflow? Or, in general, is there a way in Tensorflow to assign to each index of a tensor a value, when it is possible to define a function that returns the desired value when given as input the corresponding index?

There might be a way to do this using `tf.gather` or `tf.map_fn`.